# Bug in Clipboard.SetContent

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I'm building a UWP targeting:

Min version: 14393
Target Version: 18362

My Windows version is: 10.0.19041 Build 19041

I have the following codebehind:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace LinkTest
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage() => this.InitializeComponent();

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
            dataPackage.SetApplicationLink(new System.Uri("http://www.google.es"));
            Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
        }
    }
}
```

And the following simple UI:

```
<Page
    x:Class="LinkTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="129,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

When running this code I receive the following error in Debug or Release:

`System.Exception: 'Not enough memory resources are available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)'`

in the line:   `Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);`

I remember this same code used to work in previous versions of Windows so I think it might be potentially a bug on Windows.

Has anyone come up with the same problem? Thanks!

Comment: [`SetApplicationLink()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.setapplicationlink?view=winrt-19041): _"value: A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) with a scheme that isn't http or https that's handled by the source app"_. Are you sure you don't need `SetWebLink()`?

Comment: Pretty weird. If I try: "SetWebLink" or "SetApplicationLink" with an http url it will break. But If I use https both don't crash but don't copy anything either to the clipboard.

Comment: If I use "SetText" with any random string, it will crash always.

Comment: Try using Clipboard.SetDataObject(thingy, false); instead and let me now how it goes.

Comment: Hi, the ClipBoard under the UWP versions I'm building it doesn't appear. Clipboar has "SetContent" ,"SetContentWithOptions" and "SetHistoryItemAsContent"

Comment: Clipboard.SetDataObject(thingy, false) is probably only for WinForms or WPF but not for UWP

Comment: I made a test based on your information. But I could not reproduce the issue on my side. My UWP demo(a blank app with the code you post) runs correctly in the line of code `Not enough memory resources are available to process this command`. Does it happen everytime when you run the app? Have you tried it on other devices?

Comment: I'm puzzled because the SetText call doesn't break now. But sometimes Windows for some reason has trouble copying to the clipboard, so this might have to do with it.

Comment: Does it always happen in a specific build? That's why I asked if this happens on other devices.  If this problem cannot be reproduced stably, it will be hard to get the root reason. Currently, a simple way is to use try/catch block to handle the exception.

Comment: if I restart the computer it doesn't happen. But sometimes when I'm using Visual Studio I notice that copy paste doesn't work well on the OS, and if I restart that goes away. Maybe it was affecting the UWP Clipboard feature too

Answer (score 3):

well one thing that you are missing is setting operation type  i.e. dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;

and for copying a string, I used this and it worked fine in copying

```
private void CopyLink()
{
    DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    dataPackage.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
    dataPackage.SetText("www.google.com");
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
}
```

you can try operation type Link to set a link I am not sure of it I haven't used it before